# HttpServletResponse shall send data without printing them to client screen

Tags: java, servlets, httpresponse

I am building a web application.

Part of this web application is an ajax request from the client-side to the server:

```
$.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "get", 
      data: { 
        id: ID, 
      },
      success: function(response) {
        //parameter response contains the data sent back from the server
        //some stuff is done to this data in the rest of this function     
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred.");
      }
  });
```

On the server side I am using a servlet to handle the requests.
Once the data from the client is received, and some business logic has been  applied to it, I want to send back a simple String.

The data string would then be handled by the  following part of the ajax-function above:

```
 success: function(response) {
     //parameter response contains the data sent back from the server
     //some stuff is done to this data in the rest of this function     
 },
```

My problem is this:

I know how to send data to the screen of the client:

```
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 out.println(data);
```

However, I don't know how to send data (not to the screen but instead) to the ajax-function, so that this ajax-function can then work with the data received from the server.

The java object "response" of class "HttpServletResponse" only provides methods such as "sendError()".

I want to send the data without printing them to the screen.

How can I do that?

*************************UPDATE********************************************

I tried to use PrintWriter to send a string back to the ajax function:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("test");
```

... I then wanted to output the text "test" in an alert-message:

```
$.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "get", 
      data: { 
        latitude: location.lat(), 
        longitude: location.lng(), 
        radius: 10
      },
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Ein Fehler beim Abfragen der Daten ist aufgetreten.");
      }
  });
```

But instead of outputting an alert-message with content "test", the output consists of the whole html code of the JSP-Page from which the ajax-call had been sent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing gets sent to the "screen" specifically, it is all about where the request originates.
If you click on a link, the browser initiates the request, and the browser receives `response` and processes the output to display.

In this case, the `request` will originate from your ajax call, and therefore the ajax call will process the request and the content will be received in the `.requestText` property of the response.

You'll probably want to make sure the response content type of the `HttpServletResponse` object is set to "text/html", But since you're going so far as to use ajax, you might as well consider a step into using JSON as well.

Comment: so, I simply use the PrintWriter to send the data back
( PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  out.println(data); )?

Comment: I tested this (see updated question above) ... However, instead of the data  I'm merely getting the html-code of the JSP-Page back

Comment: Are you forwarding your request to a JSP page?

Comment: If you are writing a servlet to service an ajax call, do not involve a JSP page, you're writing the content raw, directly back.  Skip any request forwarding, as you're sending the contect directly back either through .getWriter(), or getOutputStream()

Comment: Yes, the url passed to the ajax-request is the JSP-page containing the html-code ... I guess that wasn't a good idea?

Comment: so what s the url of the ajax request supposed to be?

Comment: After all, the servlet doesn't have a url, does it?

Comment: You're new at this aren't you.  You need to configure the servlet, and the servlet URL in web.xml (or with annotations if your servlet spec/jdk is high enough).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for help! .. It works now (I used annotation to set the url of the servlet)